# How to group a list of actors in Akka?

Tags: akka

How to group a list of actors? I want to send message A to group of Actors M and message B to group of Actors N. Is there a way to give them a common name and access them through that name so I can send my messages? or Is there any better way?

Comment: Do you need message M to reach each one of the actors from A? Or you're asking this from a routing perspective: so all messages of type M will be forwarded to the group of actors A and one of those will pick it up?

Answer (score 0):

Akka provides [Routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html) for this type of functionality.  There are different routers for:

- [Broadcast](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html#BroadcastPool_and_BroadcastGroup) : looks like what you want.
- [Round Robin](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html#RoundRobinPool_and_RoundRobinGroup)
- [Random](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/routing.html#RandomPool_and_RandomGroup)
- etc...